# The contact form for bloggers becomes unresponsive approximately six hours after updating the homepage

Tags: javascript, html, cors, blogger, google-blogger-api

The contact form on my blogger website's homepage becomes unresponsive after approximately six hours. However, it starts working again when I make any updates to the homepage. I'm puzzled about why this is occurring. For instance, on my website https://www.hotelpeacefulphaplu.com.np/, after updating the homepage, the contact form operates for six hours before ceasing to function, displaying an error in the console that reads:

**NOTE(https://www.hotelpeacefulphaplu.com.np/): I have updated the page so it might working till 9:36 AM  Wednesday, December 27, 2023 GMT.**

"Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://www.blogger.com/contact-form.do. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 200."

Moreover, I have another blogger website (https://www.kalashsoap.com/p/index.html) that hasn't been updated within this six-hour timeframe. On this site, the contact form is also not functioning and shows the same error.

However, the issue does not seem to persist on other pages besides the homepage, and they do not require updates to maintain functionality.

Comment: Take a look at the `token` in the request, after the `:` ... working site `1703651202095` ... non working site `1692027664318` ... look at those values as Date's ... `2023-12-27T04:26:42.095Z` vs `2023-08-14T15:41:04.318`

Comment: @jaromanda-x is there anyway to change these payload and pass our own?

Comment: huh? they ARE your payload - your code is sending the contact form